# receive an alert when job is *not* running

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

I know how to set up a job to alert when it's running.
But I'm writing a job which is meant to run many times a day, and I don't want to be bombarded by emails, but rather I'd like a solution where I get an alert when the job *hasn't* been executed for X minutes.

This can be acheived by setting the job to alert on execution, and then setting up some process which checks for these alerts, and warns when no such alert is seen for X minutes.

I'm wondering if anyone's already implemented such a thing (or equivalent).
Supporting multiple jobs with different X values would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The danger of this approach is this: suppose you set this up. One day you receive no emails. What does this mean?

It *could* mean

- the supposed-to-be-running job is running successfully (and silently), and so the absence-of-running monitor job has nothing to say

or alternatively

- the supposed-to-be-running job is NOT running successfully, but the absence-of-running monitor job has ALSO failed

or even

- your server has caught fire, and can't send any emails even if it wants to

---

Don't seek to avoid receiving success messages - instead devise a strategy for coping with them. Because the only way to know that a job is running successfully is getting a message which says precisely this.

Comment: Outlook Rules can filter on body content and size - I have in the past had rules which filtered small messages from a server to a 'these are probably success messages' folder for infrequent review, while large messages (typically including an error log) stayed in Inbox (or wherever) for immediate review. The good people over at [sf] proably have lots of ideas; I was half tempted to suggest this question would be better there.